# Linked List reading from a file

Tags: c

I have a struct as the following

```
struct employeeData
   {
     int EMP_ID;
     char name[20];
     int dept;
     int rank;
     int salary;

     struct employeeData *next;
   };
```

I created a function

```
void initializeList(struct employeeData *List)
```

which I am trying to read in information from a file in the format of

```
12   Bob   2     1    65000
13   Sally  5   3    30000
```

I currently attempted

```
void initializeList(struct employeeData *List)

{

    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("empInfo.txt","r");

    while (ifp != 0)
{

    fscanf(ifp, " %d %s %d %d %d ", &List->EMP_ID, &List->name, &List->dept, &List->rank, &List->salary);

    List->next;

}

    fclose(ifp);

}
```

This has to be a linked list which I know needs Malloc somewhere but I am stuck.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Good news! You can look [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941820/linked-list-text-file-loop) for "any" help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct employeeData {
    int EMP_ID;
    char name[20];
    int dept;
    int rank;
    int salary;

    struct employeeData *next;
}EMP;

EMP *new_EMP(void){
    EMP *node = calloc(1, sizeof(EMP));
    if(!node){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create an employee.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return node;
}

EMP *readf_EMP(FILE *fp){
    EMP emp = { .next = NULL };
    if(5==fscanf(fp, "%d %19s %d %d %d", &emp.EMP_ID, emp.name, &emp.dept, &emp.rank, &emp.salary)){
        EMP *node = new_EMP();
        *node = emp;
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}

EMP *initializeList(void){
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("empInfo.txt","r");
    EMP *np, *head=NULL, *curr;

    while (np = readf_EMP(ifp)){
        if(!head)
            head = curr = np;
        else
            curr = curr->next = np;
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    return head;
}
```